# How to redirect these using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have many URL like these

```
/user.cfm?clock-work-sr400&id=1617
/user.cfm?coast-guard-bike&id=1711
/user.cfm?cobalt-mania&id=1381
/user.cfm?cojones-girder-flathead&id=1978
```

I tried this

```
Redirect 301 /user.cfm?clock-work-sr400&id=1617 http://www.newdomain.com/new-page.html
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I redirect those links to another domain pages?

Comment: all of them to the same new page?

Comment: No not same new page, I have new page for every links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod_rewrite` for the same.

A sample code

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^user.cfm?clock-work-sr400&id" [OR] 

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^user.cfm?coast-guard-bike&id" [OR] 

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^user.cfm?cobalt-mania&id" 

RewriteRule (.*) http://newdomain/newpage.html [R,L]
```

If you want a one to one mapping then below should work fine

```
Redirect 301 /user.cfm?clock-work-sr400&id=1617 http://www.newdomain.com/new-page.html
```

For first example make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled and for second `mod_alias`

Comment: Hi Thank you but its not redirecting

Comment: Rizoy please provide the urls you wanted to redirect.Is there some pattern? If not then it is going to be one on one redirection rule.

Comment: Hi Ankit, my current url like this www.mydomain.com/user.cfm?clock-work-sr400&id=1617 and yes I need one to one redirect, I have new page for each and every links.

Comment: Updated the answer. Also enable the rewrite log and check it along with access.log and error.log